# Circle:Sphere::Ellipse:? What should replace the question mark below?

Tags: geometry

> Circle:Sphere::Ellipse:?

Assuming it's a valid analogy, answer the above question. In case it's invalid, explain how.

Comment: Please give us either (1) where you got the question or (2) what you think about it. It's fine, but needs one of those two things.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid

Comment: Please improve your title, and state the problem in the body of the Question in a self-contained fashion, emphasizing the use of complete sentences to frame the problem.

Comment: Agreed with hardmath; I dislike "a:b::c:?" as notation, partly because it's extremely un-Googleable. If you type into Google "a is to b as c is to what?", its first hit is to the Wikipedia article on Ellipsoid (although that is true with the compact notation too).

Answer (score 2):

It should be an [Ellipsoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid).

Just as a sphere is a three dimensional analogue of a circle, an ellipsoid is a three dimensional analogue of an ellipse.